# Download Intent

Tags: android, download, android-download-manager

I've been developing a movie application that user can download movie via direct link.
At end part I have problem.
Does android have intent for downloading ? 
I want that  when user click one button , one dialog showed and user can choose one of downloader(download applications), do they want !
Just like when we click on one direct link in browser.

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog?rq=1

Comment: @Xander I see it 
this question is about create one custom download manger .
I want one intent to choose downloder to download.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try this below

```
 Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://apache.claz.org/nifi/1.1.0/nifi-1.1.0-bin.tar.gz");
 Intent it  = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri);
 startActivity(it);
```

this well show up a browsers list, you can choose one from them and the download will begin.

Comment: I tried that . this way is good for downloading binary file as like .zip or .tar
But in my case is movie format like .mkv or .mp4

Comment: _Download_ or _play_ depends on your web server config, if you add `add_header Content-type Application/Octet-Stream; ` to your nginx server configuration, then the Browser will download but not to play it. try this url  `Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://test.issll.com/demo/videoviewdemo.mp4"); `

Comment: Some devices don't work with this way. A tab of browser dissapear as soon as itshows up...

Answer (score 0):

```
new Thread(new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        File outputFile=new File("//sdcard//downloadCase.mp3");
        try
        {
            if(!outputFile.exists())
        {
            outputFile.createNewFile();
        }
        else
        {
            outputFile.delete();
            outputFile.createNewFile();
        }
        //CHANGE URL HERE
        URL u = new URL("http://dl.blugaa.com/lq.blugaa.com/cdn7/3c0883064579a332dd7b627e3a904284/ylzuv/Mere%20Kol-(Mr-Jatt.com).mp3");
        URLConnection conn = u.openConnection();
        int contentLength = conn.getContentLength();

        DataInputStream stream = new DataInputStream(u.openStream());

        byte[] buffer = new byte[contentLength];
        stream.readFully(buffer);
        stream.close();

        DataOutputStream fos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outputFile));
        fos.write(buffer);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            return; // swallow a 404
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            return; // swallow a 404
        }

    }
}).start();
```